# Add ring feature not available in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have installed the version 2.18.24 in QGIS and apparently the plugin 'Digitizing tools' does not include the feture 'add ring' but it was replaced by 'fill ring with a new feature'. However, somehow I cannot create this new feature neither.
Case this would work... if I want a hole in the polygon, do I have to create a feature and then delete it? 
Do anyone have some information on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add ring` tool is part of the `advanced digitizing toolbar`, which is not a plugin but part of the default installation.

go to the menu `view` then `toolbars` and the 1st one is the  `advanced digitizing toolbar`

Answer (score 1):

Add Ring still exists in QGIS 2.18.23. I don't have the latest version but there is no difference between 2.18.24 and 2.18.23, because the former is just a minor update which will not remove Add Ring tool:

[image]